# How to firstly configure Hashicorp Vault with local jwt/ca certs

Tags: hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I am trying to config Vaults Helm Chart. What I do is:

1. Deploy with my CI/CD tool and wait for the replicas to be available
2. Enter the UI and init Vault
3. Restore manually with my backup file
4. ssh into the pod with `kubectl exec -it pod -- sh`
5. vault login
6. `vault write auth/kubernetes/config token_reviewer_jwt="$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" kubernetes_host="https://$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR:443" kubernetes_ca_cert=@/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`

Step 6 is what causes all my problems. I can't logout which sounds like an extreme security risk. Isn't there a way to automate this? I've read the docs, there seems to be an agent, but it's very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`rm ~/.vault-token`

is the right answer.